# How do I blast Mettaton ex arms off?

Tags: undertale

I've looked on the internet countless times and I can't seem to Blow his arms off!
The only thing that helped me the tiniest bit is shooting his heart but the only thing that happens is I go down to 15 hp. And I can only get to abbout 5000 fans or followers. Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

Maettaton EX will do a heart-to-heart a few times. When he does, just shoot the heart. After two rounds of heart-to-hearts, his arms will fall off. One more heart-to-heart, and his legs will fall off. If you get his limbs to fall off, you only need 10k viewers. Otherwise, you need 12k.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the viewers to 10k I believe. He will then do a few attacks and do a heart to heart. Break his heart again and the arms should come off. If you are doing a pacifist run that would be when you throw the stick.